# First Classification of Finite Subgroups of $SO(3)$

Tags: group-theory, geometry, finite-groups, euclidean-geometry, math-history

One can find a classification of all isomorphism types of finite subgroups of $SO(3)$ on, say, GroupProps: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_subgroups_of_SO(3,R). However, I would like to know who is generally agreed to have first found this classification. Does anyone know?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Possibly it would be a better fit there, but I am doubtful it would get an answer. Its a bit too technical (looking at the HSM front page).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos What about this feels more historical than mathematical to you? The result happened in the past, but that doesn’t necessarily feel “historical.” I don’t think all reference/author requests of this kind should be shuffled off to HSM.

Comment: It says [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) that questions concerning history and development of mathematics should be posted at the StackExchange site that I mentioned.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos "should" is not the correct word. The link actually says "There are certain subjects that, while still on-topic here, *might be better addressed* by one of our sister sites" (emphasis mine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/finite+rotation+group#ClassificationOfFiniteSubgroupsOfSO3) the earliest proof is due to Klein:

> Felix Klein, chapter I of Vorlesungen über das Ikosaeder und die
>   Auflösung der Gleichungen vom fünften Grade, 1884, translated as
>   Lectures on the Icosahedron and the Resolution of Equations of Degree
>   Five by George Morrice 1888, [online version](https://archive.org/details/cu31924059413439/page/n10)